# what is the meaning of the verb "Blow up" here

Tags: calculus

Does anyone know what the meaning of the verb "Blow up" in the text below is?

> To evaluate the integral
> $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}{f(x)dx}$$
> We
> consider the corresponding contour integral
> $$\oint\limits_{C}{f(z)dz}$$
> around a closed path C that consists of a semicircle S located at the top of the x axis with center of origin and radius R and a line segment from -R to R.
> we assume that f(z) has some poles in the upper half plane and if we choose R large enough, then C encloses all these poles. By
> the residue theorem we then obtain
>
> $$\oint\limits_{c}{f(z)dz}=\int_{s}{f(z)dz}+\int\limits_{-R}^{R}{f(x)dx}=2\pi i\sum{Res\ f(z)}$$
>
> where the sum consists of all the residues of f(z) at the points in the upper half-plane at
> which f(z) has a pole. From this we have
> $$\int\limits_{-R}^{R}{f(x)dx}=2\pi i\sum{Res\ f(z)}-\int_{s}{f(z)dz}$$
> Now by blowing up the closed contour C , the value of the integral over the semicircle S approaches
> zero and we have
> $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}{f(x)dx}=2\pi i\sum{Res\ f(z)}$$

Comment: $R$ tends to infinity.

Comment: Try to draw the circuit $C$: segment $[-R,R]$ on the $x$-axis and semicircle $S$ with center the origin and radius $R$. When you increase the radius $R$, the semicircle will expand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metaphorically, it means to use your lungs (or a mechanical pump) and inflate the contour with air, like a balloon.

More concretely, it means we steadily increase the size of the contour, in this case by letting $R$ grow towards infinity.